# Get file mime type on pre_save in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mime-types

I would like to save the file mime type by getting it on pre_save signal.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.db import models
import magic

class Media (models.Media):
    file = models.FileField()
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, editable=False)

def media_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.content_type:
        mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
        instance.content_type = mime.from_buffer(instance.file.read())
pre_save.connect(media_pre_save, sender=Media)
```

But I'm getting `application/x-empty` when I view it in db. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use magic to verify file type in a Django form clean method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647401/how-does-one-use-magic-to-verify-file-type-in-a-django-form-clean-method)

Comment: Thanks, but that one gets the file from form object, is it possible to get it from instance? I would like to do the same thing but with the given parameters on `media_pre_save`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to get the uploaded file absolute path and using the `from_file` method of `magic` like so:

```
instance.content_type = magic.from_file(instance.file.path, mime=True)
```

Updated answer:

I sometimes get empty file if file is a bit large so I have to "seek" from the beginning of the uploaded file and using the `from_buffer` method of `magic` like so:

```
instance.file.seek(0)
instance.content_type = magic.from_buffer(instance.file.read(), mime=True)
```

I owe the answer to the following links:
[Edit uploaded file (djangos FileField) using pre_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472164/edit-uploaded-file-djangos-filefield-using-pre-save-signal/) and
https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic